# Spark Streaming works in Local mode but "stages fail" with "could not initialize class" in Client/Cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a Spark + Kafka streaming app that runs fine in Local mode, however when I try to launch it in yarn + local/cluster mode I get several errors like below

The first error I always see is

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.1 in stage 3.0 (TID 9, ip-xxx-24-129-36.ec2.internal, executor 2): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class TestStreaming$
        at TestStreaming$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TestStreaming.scala:60)
        at TestStreaming$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TestStreaming.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:917)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:917)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Next error I get is

> ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1541786030000 ms.0

followed by

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class

Spark version 2.1.0
Scala 2.11
Kafka version 10

Part of my code when I launch it loads the config in main. I pass this config file at runtime with -conf AFTER the jar (see below). I'm not quite sure but must I pass this config to the executors as well?

I launch my streaming app with the command below. One shows Local mode, the other shows client mode.

> runJar = myProgram.jar
>   loggerPath=/path/to/log4j.properties
>
> mainClass=TestStreaming
>
> logger=-DPHDTKafkaConsumer.app.log4j=$loggerPath
>
> confFile=application.conf
>
> -----------Local Mode----------
>   SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10 nohup spark2-submit --driver-java-options
>   "$logger" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=$logger" --class
>   $mainClass --master local[4] $runJar -conf $confFile &
>
> -----------Client Mode----------
>   SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10 nohup spark2-submit --master yarn --conf >"spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=$logger" --conf >"spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=$logger" --class $mainClass  $runJar -conf >$confFile &

Here is my code below. Been battling this for over a week now.

```
import Util.UtilFunctions
import UtilFunctions.config
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.log4j.Logger


object TestStreaming extends Serializable {

  @transient lazy val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    logger.info("Starting app")

    UtilFunctions.loadConfig(args)
    UtilFunctions.loadLogger()

    val props: Map[String, String] = setKafkaProperties()

    val topic = Set(config.getString("config.TOPIC_NAME"))

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName(config.getString("config.SPARK_APP_NAME"))
      .set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config(conf)
      .getOrCreate()

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(10))
    ssc.sparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO")
    ssc.checkpoint(config.getString("config.SPARK_CHECKPOINT_NAME"))

    val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topic, props))
    val distRecordsStream = kafkaStream.map(record => (record.key(), record.value()))
    distRecordsStream.window(Seconds(10), Seconds(10))
    distRecordsStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      if(!rdd.isEmpty()) {
        rdd.foreach(record => {
          println(record._2) //value from kafka
        })
      }
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
    ssc.stop()
  }

  def setKafkaProperties(): Map[String, String] = {

    val deserializer = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
    val zookeeper = config.getString("config.ZOOKEEPER")
    val offsetReset = config.getString("config.OFFSET_RESET")
    val brokers = config.getString("config.BROKERS")
    val groupID = config.getString("config.GROUP_ID")
    val autoCommit = config.getString("config.AUTO_COMMIT")
    val maxPollRecords = config.getString("config.MAX_POLL_RECORDS")
    val maxPollIntervalms = config.getString("config.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS")

    val props = Map(
      "bootstrap.servers" -> brokers,
      "zookeeper.connect" -> zookeeper,
      "group.id" -> groupID,
      "key.deserializer" -> deserializer,
      "value.deserializer" -> deserializer,
      "enable.auto.commit" -> autoCommit,
      "auto.offset.reset" -> offsetReset,
      "max.poll.records" -> maxPollRecords,
      "max.poll.interval.ms" -> maxPollIntervalms)
    props
  }

}
```